# NoReverseMatch error showing up randomly for Django CMS pages

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I am using Django CMS 2.3 for several projects with analogous configuration. The strange thing is that for one project I keep getting NoReverseMatch error for random pages at random times:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'cms_page_change_template' with arguments '(12L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

After refreshing the buggy page it works again. It seems from the traceback that the error happens trying to render the CMSToolbar. I get this error only on a server with mod_wsgi. I can't reproduce it locally on the development server.

Do you have any clues, what could be wrong? Have you experienced something similar?

Comment: hunch: try deleting all .pyc files in your project and virtualenv and then restarting everything.

Comment: I am able to replicate this error on a development environment even now with django-cms3Beta.
I have put this issue on github with django-cms, [here.](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2069)